# Why my RoR destroy links don't work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding, destroy

there is a problem puzzling me for quite a time now related to Ruby on Rails applications. I tested the very same workflow in 3 different environments and in none of them I am able to get the "destroy" links to work!

Using this setup:

- RVM 1.17.4
- Ruby 1.9.3p327
- Rails 3.2.9

Then, executed, literally, these commands:

```
$ rails new foo
$ cd foo/
$ rails g scaffold bar title:string
$ rake db:migrate
```

It generated this controller:

```
  # DELETE /bars/1
  # DELETE /bars/1.json
  def destroy
    @bar = Bar.find(params[:id])
    @bar.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to bars_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

This is the destroy line in the view:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', bar, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

This is the code in the final page:

```
<a href="/bars/1" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Destroy</a>
```

In the layout I have these:

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

And in the application.js I have these:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

These are the lines in the html output:

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bars.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

These are the routes:

```
    bars GET    /bars(.:format)          bars#index
         POST   /bars(.:format)          bars#create
 new_bar GET    /bars/new(.:format)      bars#new
edit_bar GET    /bars/:id/edit(.:format) bars#edit
     bar GET    /bars/:id(.:format)      bars#show
         PUT    /bars/:id(.:format)      bars#update
         DELETE /bars/:id(.:format)      bars#destroy
```

Anyone came to the same results? Why doesn't it work?

The workarounds I found in the Internet are suggesting the javascript is not properly loaded and sometimes it is suggested to change the action from DELETE to GET. Some suggest changing the link for a button. Anyway, the confirmation never shows up and it is really annoying to rewrite all the destroy actions in all views.

Comment: Why don't you have an @ infront of bar in your link_to?

Comment: Hi TomJ, it is because this is in the index page, so it is inside a loop. The `@bar` is actually a list of all entries. =D

Comment: And what does your console log say? Should look something like:

Started DELETE "/posts/2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-29 16:17:36 -0500
Processing by PostsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"Z7MWoO6XliYLHX4qUrnrnrS23QnTTxltq+sCmRhmZ9Y=", "id"=>"2"}
  Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "2"]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (17.6ms)  DELETE FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ?  [["id", 2]]
   (36.3ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/posts
Completed 302 Found in 61ms (ActiveRecord: 54.3ms)

Answer (score 1):

Given the html, there should be no problem. Therefore this is likely a client-side problem, not a server-side problem.

As you said...

> The workarounds I found in the Internet are suggesting the javascript is not properly loaded...

1. You probably have a browser without javascript support, or else you have disabled javascript.

   Which browsers have you tested this in? Try Firefox, and in the **Options** window, ensure the **Content** tab has **Enable javascript** checked.
2. Alternatively, go to `/assets/jquery.js?body=1` and `/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1` in your browser to ensure that the javascript framework files are there. If not, you need to add these to your assets directory, and *may* need to run `rake assets:precompile` if you are running in a production environment.

Answer (score 0):

If JavaScript is enabled and you sure that *destroy* action must work, but link doesn't send the right HTTP_METHOD = DELETE, and routes setting are right, **then try to change DOCTYPE**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```